# C++ CppCheck algorithm suggestion (std::find_if instead of raw loop) pertinence

Tags: c++, stl, cppcheck

CppCheck suggest me to replace one of my code by a STL algorithm, I'm not against it, but I don't know how to replace it. I'm pretty sure this is a bad suggestion (There is warning about experimental functionalities in CppCheck).

Here is the code :

```
    /* Cutted beginning of the function ... */

    for ( const auto & program : m_programs )
    {
        if ( program->compare(vertexShader, tesselationControlShader, tesselationEvaluationShader, geometryShader, fragmentShader) )
        {
            TraceInfo(Classname, "A program has been found matching every shaders.");

            return program;
        }
    }

    return nullptr;
} /* End of the function */
```

And near the if condition I got : "Consider using std::find_if algorithm instead of a raw loop."

I tried to use it, but I can't get the return working anymore... Should I ignore this suggestion ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you may need to use that finding function not once. So, according to DRY, you need to separate the block where you invoke an std::find_if algorithm to a distinct wrapper function.

```
{

    // ... function beginning

    auto found = std::find_if(m_programs.cbegin(), m_programs.cend(), 
       [&](const auto& prog)
       {
           bool b = prog->compare(...);
           if (b)
                 TraceInfo(...);
           return b;
       });

    if (found == m_programs.cend())
       return nullptr;

    return *found;

}
```

The suggestion is good. An STL algorithm migth be able to choose an appropriate
approach based on your container type.

Furthermore, I suggest you to use a self-balancing container like an std::set.

```
// I don't know what kind of a pointer you use. 
using pProgType = std::shared_pointer<ProgType>;

bool compare_progs(const pProgType &a, const pProgType &b)
{
   return std::less(*a, *b);
}

std::set<std::shared_pointer<prog_type>, 
    std::integral_constant<decltype(&compare_progs), &compare_progs>> progs.
```

This is a sorted container, so you will spend less time for searching a program by a value, given you implement a compare operator (which is invoked by std::less).

If you can use an stl function, use it. This way you will not have to remember what you invented, because stl is properly documented and safe to use.

Comment: Ok, I got the idea now... Its working ! But, for a stylistic point of view, it's a bit darker no ?

Comment: I see what you want me to improve with my compare function (which is not correctly named as it appears now). In fact, I can't really compare two program in that place, because the new program isn't existing yet. I'm just watching against living programs if I really need to build a new flavor of a program based on shaders footprint. But I love the idea, noted ! :)

Comment: @SébastienBémelmans you are better of using std::set::insert then. It would check if the key exists and then emplace an instance. You will need to implement an `operator==` then. Also, check out https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set

Comment: So if I follow your idea, I will change my class member "std::vector< std::shared_ptr< Program > > m_programs;" by "std::set::< std::shared_ptr< Program > > m_programs;" ?

Comment: Well, yes. But don't forget the second argument, which is a compare function, wrapped with std::integral_constant. That will enable the container to compare objects, not pointers. Though I'm not sure that your approach in general is good, given you have to search if there is a shader program with same parameters. I would avoid the possibility of just having two similar programs rather than run that kind of check.

Comment: Rather than adding the tracing to the predicate, I would move it out to the found case. `if (found != m_programs.cend()) { TraceInfo(Classname, "A program has been found matching every shaders."); return *found; } return nullptr;`